# A) precede_list (X, Y)

Tags: prolog

`precede_list(X, Y)` is true when the list `X` precedes the `Y` list.

Example:

```
precede_list([1,2], [1, 2, 3]).
```

So in this example the correct answers will be `[],[1],[1,2]`

What predicate should I write in order to get this answers?

Comment: Can you please show the code that you have attempted so far and ask a more specific question on where you are stuck?

Comment: and `[2]` isn't a correct answer?

Comment: No [2] isnt a correct answer .we want something like the reverse list but we dont take the head firs, we take the Tail .Anotther example: ?-precede_list([1,2,3)],[1,2,3,4,5,6].-True(the answers are[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[])

Comment: I found the answer precede_list([],[H|T]).
precede_list([X|Ta],[X|Tai]):-precede_list(Ta,Tai).

Answer (score 0):

```
precede_list([],[H|T]).
precede_list([X|Ta],[X|Tai]):-precede_list(Ta,Tai).
```

Comment: Congratulations, you independently discovered `append/3` :) what you call "preceding list" is usually known as "prefix", `prefix/2` might be [available in the standard library](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prefix/2) ([here is the implementation you re-discovered](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#prefix/2)), and is the same as `append(Prefix, _, List)`.